# ERROR: Could not build wheels for mmcv-full, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

python = 3.10

pytorch = 2.2.1+cu118

pip install mmcv-full

```
    running install_scripts
      C:\Users\omras\miniconda3\envs\transseg1\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py:109: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
        if get_flag("Py_DEBUG", hasattr(sys, "gettotalrefcount"), warn=(impl == "cp")):
      error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LICENSE'
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mmcv-full
  Running setup.py clean for mmcv-full
Failed to build mmcv-full
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mmcv-full, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was:

```
pip install mmcv-full -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cu118/torch2.1.0/index.html
```